# Proving that a quadrilateral is cyclic

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

How would I prove that BCFH is cyclic?
[image]

ABCD is parallelogram
E, F Always lie within ABCD. AECF is a parallelogram aswell. H is the Intersection (other than A) of the Circumcircles of the triangles AFD and ABE.

I have tried to prove that the Diagonals of BHFC are the same, by trying to find relations between Angles (for example you can say that due the triangles ABE and DFC being congruent the angles ∠DFC and ∠AEB are the same, furthermore since H is on the same circle as E the inscribed formula states that ∠AHB = ∠AEB = ∠DFC.) but I've been out of luck.

Im currently trying the approach of defining each point by two variable coordinates and then, using the Formulas for circumcircles, trying to find an Intersection between $\odot(BFC)$, $\odot(AEB)$ and $\odot(AFD)$.
But this approach is obviously very tedious and prone to errors and id still like to know if there's a geometric way to prove it.

Comment: I think one important point could be missing ---- CB is tangent to the circle. Note that you must show some of your effort before you can get any answer/hint.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: @Mick: Tangency is not required.

Comment: @ImNotSure: Angle-chasing worked for me to show that opposite angles in $\square BCFH$ are supplementary. With all the parallel lines and inscribed angles, there are lots of congruences to chase through. After a few tries, I managed to find a pair of "independent" angles in terms of which I could write other angles to give a relatively-straightforward chase, but lots of paths work.

Comment: Do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

For the configuration shown below, define $\alpha := \angle BCF$ and $\beta:=\angle ADF$ ...

[image]

$$\begin{align}
\angle EAD = \alpha &\qquad \angle EBC = \beta &&(\text{parallels})\tag1 \\[4pt]
\angle AEB &= \alpha+\beta &&(\text{parallels})\tag2 \\[4pt]
\angle AHB &= \alpha+\beta &&(\text{Inscribed Angle Theorem in $\bigcirc  AEB$}) \tag3 \\[4pt]
\angle AHF &= 180^\circ-\beta &&(\text{$\square AHFD$ is cyclic}) \tag4
\end{align}$$

Therefore,
$$\angle BHF = 360^\circ-\angle AHB-\angle AHF=180^\circ-\alpha \tag5$$
so that $\square BHFC$ is cyclic. $\square$

Line $(4)$ depends upon $A$, $H$, $F$, $D$ appearing *in that order* on their circle. Adjusting the argument for the order $A$, $F$, $H$, $D$ (with which $\angle AHF=\beta$) is left as an exercise to the reader. (There *should* be an argument that neatly avoids such case-work, but I haven't found it.)

Comment: You are right about that. My work is just a very special case. I shall have it deleted shortly.